# React useEffect warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component causes switch statement to render wrong component

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I built a confirmation component to display information from my server whether a user as registered via a signup:

The outcomes which will be displayed via react are either:

a) successfully verified their account by clicking a link in a confirmation email I sent

b) account has been verified already

c) unable to find a user for this token

At first blush I thought it worked, however I noticed two things which I believe are related to the error:

One is the error:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

Also despite using a switch statement, the negative component gets mounted instead of the success component? I am using a `break` keyword but somehow the rendering of the component falls through.

Anyway here is the component:

```
export function Confirmation({
  match,
  setError,
  setResponseMessage,
  resetUserAcoountVerified,
  userHasBeenVerified,
  error,
  responseMessage,
  accountNotVerified
}) {
  // var [mountedComponent, setMountedComponent] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true;
    axios
      .get(`/users/confirmation/${match.params.token}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (isSubscribed) {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            isSubscribed ? setResponseMessage(response.data.msg) : null;
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        if (error.response.status === 404) {
          resetUserAcoountVerified();
          setError(true);
          isSubscribed ? setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg) : null;
        }
        if (error.response.status === 400) {
          userHasBeenVerified();
          setError(true);

          isSubscribed ? setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg) : null;
        }
      });
    return () => (isSubscribed = false);
  }, []);

  const isNull = value => typeof value === 'object' && !value;

  console.log('error ', error);

  console.log('accountNotVerified ', accountNotVerified);

  let response;
  switch (error) {
    case accountNotVerified == true && error === false:
      response = <Message positive header={responseMessage[0]} />;
      break;
    case accountNotVerified == false && error == true:
      response = <Message negative header={responseMessage[0]} />;
      break;
    case isNull(accountNotVerified) && error:
      response = <Message negative header={responseMessage[0]} />;
  }

  return <>{response}</>;
```

}

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

This is my take based on the kind contributions and insight of Evert and Peter:

```
function isConfirmation() {
    var [showApi, setShowApi] = useState(true);

    function conirmationCall() {
      return axios
        .get(`/users/confirmation/${match.params.token}`)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            return response;
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          if (error.response.status === 404) {
            resetUserAcoountVerified();
            setError(true);
            setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg);
            return error;
          }
          if (error.response.status === 400) {
            userHasBeenVerified();
            setError(true);
            setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg);
            return error;
          }
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      var mounted = true;

      conirmationCall()
        .then(status => {
          () => setShowApi(prev => !prev);
          console.log('status', status);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
      return function() {
        mounted = false;
      };
    }, []);

    if (error) {
      return showApi && <Message negative header={responseMessage[0]} />;
    }
    return showApi && <Message positive header={responseMessage[0]} />;
  }
```

Comment: Oh thank you kindly Sunil! I'll have to check it out!

Answer (score 2):

This is not how switch works. Switch compares 1 value to 1 or more other values.

So this:

```js
  switch (error) {
    case accountNotVerified == true && error === false:
      response = <Message positive header={responseMessage[0]} />;
      break;
    case accountNotVerified == false && error == true:
      response = <Message negative header={responseMessage[0]} />;
      break;
    case isNull(accountNotVerified) && error:
      response = <Message negative header={responseMessage[0]} />;
  }
```

Turns into something like this:

```js
  switch (error) {
    case true:
      response = <Message positive header={responseMessage[0]} />;
      break;
    case false:
      response = <Message negative header={responseMessage[0]} />;
      break;
    case true:
      response = <Message negative header={responseMessage[0]} />;
  }
```

So you are comparing `error` to true and/or false (loosely).

I would suggest you re-read the documentation on the `switch` statement, but in your case I think I would suggest to not use `switch` but just return.

```js
    if (accountNotVerified && !error) {
      return <Message positive header={responseMessage[0]} />;
    }
    if (!accountNotVerified && error) {
      return <Message negative header={responseMessage[0]} />;
    }
    return <Message negative header={responseMessage[0]} />;
```

But looking at this again, i think this can be simplified even more:

```js
    if (error) {
      return <Message negative header={responseMessage[0]} />;
    }
    return <Message positive header={responseMessage[0]} />;
```

Comment: Thanks Evert I think I'm going with this logic for the rendering! Much easier to read. I have a habit of over complicating things!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in your case is the `async` api call, and when the response is returning, the component could be `unmounted`. This case the `setError()` (And you can not set any state on unmounted component. **Nor** `setError()`). 
 I suggest you to define a new variable, `let mounted = true;`, and check weather the component is `mounted`. I see that you have a variable, what exactly doing this thing. You can use that `let isSubscribed = true;`.

```
export function Confirmation({
  match,
  setError,
  setResponseMessage,
  resetUserAcoountVerified,
  userHasBeenVerified,
  error,
  responseMessage,
  accountNotVerified
}) {
  // var [mountedComponent, setMountedComponent] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true;
    let mounted = true;
    axios
      .get(`/users/confirmation/${match.params.token}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (isSubscribed && mounted) {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            isSubscribed ? setResponseMessage(response.data.msg) : null;
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        if (error.response.status === 404 && mounted) {
          resetUserAcoountVerified();
          setError(true);
          isSubscribed ? setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg) : null;
        }
        if (error.response.status === 400 && mounted) {
          userHasBeenVerified();
          setError(true);

          isSubscribed ? setResponseMessage(error.response.data.msg) : null;
        }
      });
    return () => {
      isSubscribed = false;
      mounted = false;
    }
  }, []);

  const isNull = value => typeof value === 'object' && !value;

  console.log('error ', error);

  console.log('accountNotVerified ', accountNotVerified);

  let response;
  switch (error) {
    case accountNotVerified == true && error === false:
      response = <Message positive header={responseMessage[0]} />;
      break;
    case accountNotVerified == false && error == true:
      response = <Message negative header={responseMessage[0]} />;
      break;
    case isNull(accountNotVerified) && error:
      response = <Message negative header={responseMessage[0]} />;
  }

  return <>{response}</>;
```

Comment: Thank you Peter for the help. After reading your logic I was thinking "Ah yes, this makes sense" However I'm still getting.

`index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.` Puzzling!

Comment: can you check in other components maybe? I have created a sandbox to you, where you can check how it works: `https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-tereshkova-5bjbv?file=/src/App.js`
If you toggle the component before the `fakeCall` finishing with and without mounted check, you will see the difference.

Comment: I have made a comment in line 29 `// remove this check  for test purpose`

Comment: forget to clear the `useEffect` on `unmount`: `return () => (mounted = false);`. Now you can check it

Comment: Thanks so much Peter, I'll update you soon as it's the fourth and i have a little one!

Comment: Hey Peter, I made an update. But not sure why its still indicating the `no-op` Also I found it curious the `console.log('status', status);` in the confirmation call returns `undefined`. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Wait Peter, just realized I didn't return anything in those calls! LOL

Comment: So I made the update and added the return values, but still getting the error!

Comment: I see. So you calling an async function if the component still monted. And what happens if the component will unmount during the function finishing? I mean you checking the mounted at a wrong place. Maybe pass the `mounted` value in a function, and check it when the `axios` have fetched the data

Comment: Or you should set the state in `then`or `catch` after a `mounted` check. not in the `conirmationCall `

Comment: Think you can illustrate what you mean?